# jssor bootstrap caption not working

Tags: jssor

I implementing jssor bootstrap slider on my web and I want to add caption with transition, but I got an error Uncaught ReferenceError: $JssorCaptionSlider$ is not defined.

Here my javascript

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    //Rotate Overlap
    { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 }, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: $Jease$.$Swing, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 }, $Shift: 90 } },
    //Switch
    { $Duration: 1400, x: 0.25, $Zoom: 1.5, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InWave, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InSine }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1400, x: -0.25, $Zoom: 1.5, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InWave, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InSine }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10 } },
    //Rotate Relay
    { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1 }, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1 }, $ZIndex: -10, $Shift: 600 } }
];

var _CaptionTransitions = [
    {$Duration:900,x:-0.6,y:-0.6,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutSine,$Top:$Jease$.$InOutSine},$Opacity:2}
];

var options = {
    $AutoPlay: 1,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
    $Idle: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $Jease$.$OutQuad
    $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

    $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
        $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,             //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
        $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
        $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
    },

    $CaptionSliderOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
        $PlayInMode: 1,
        $PlayOutMode: 3
    },

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
    },

    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 12,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1                                //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    }
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth - 30);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

});

and html

```
 <div id="slider1_container" style="visibility: hidden; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 950px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;

            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%; height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/loading.gif'); ?>) no-repeat center center;

            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 950px; height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src2="<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/img1.jpg'); ?>" />
                <div u=caption t="wedoit" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 40%;">
                    "We do it Fast and Track our mails"
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src2="<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/img2.jpg'); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src2="<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/img3.jpg'); ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssorb05 div           (normal)
            .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .av           (active)
            .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb05 {
                position: absolute;
            }
            .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of bullet elment */
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: url(<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/b05.png'); ?>) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .jssorb05 div { background-position: -7px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover { background-position: -37px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 .av { background-position: -67px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover { background-position: -97px -7px; }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype"></div>
        </div>
        <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 11 css */
            /*
            .jssora11l                  (normal)
            .jssora11r                  (normal)
            .jssora11l:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora11r:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora11l.jssora11ldn      (mousedown)
            .jssora11r.jssora11rdn      (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora11l, .jssora11r {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                /* size of arrow element */
                width: 37px;
                height: 37px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background: url(<?php echo themes_url('images/carousel/a11.png'); ?>) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .jssora11l { background-position: -11px -41px; }
            .jssora11r { background-position: -71px -41px; }
            .jssora11l:hover { background-position: -131px -41px; }
            .jssora11r:hover { background-position: -191px -41px; }
            .jssora11l.jssora11ldn { background-position: -251px -41px; }
            .jssora11r.jssora11rdn { background-position: -311px -41px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora11l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora11r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Bootstrap Carousel</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think they have removed Caption Transitions from the latest version: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html

I have an earlier version of the plugin with the Caption Transitions working, but for some weird reason the transitions only work in firefox. in other browsers only the fade effect is working

Comment: Yes, I've found out that they are now used slider maker, thanks to your response. :)